# How to access proxy's handler value in console?

Tags: javascript

I have an object called this.account the response is coming in the proxy handler.
in handler there is property call originaltarget array I want to store the array in the variable

I tried "this.accounts.originalTaget" command but i am unable to get it array

Here is img : https://ibb.co/xFsWSJT

Comment: Can you show a minimal working example. Look here for more information https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex

Comment: Hi Rahul , i have obj "this.account" which have an array. i want to pass that array to differnt array ref:https://ibb.co/4ZZQ4kX